# how to get all of a query

Tags: sql, t-sql

i have the following code. i am trying to get all the rows from billing where pws_endchargedate is less the todays date. meaning that even if one row-end charge date in billing is greater than todays date it will not show up. right now i am getting results that are includes some assets that have rows of billing with endchargedate bigger than todays date.

```
select distinct billing.pws_AssetIdName
from pws_billingchargeitems billing
join pws_assetservice assetser on billing.pws_AssetId=assetser.pws_AssetId
join pws_asset asset on asset.pws_assetId=billing.pws_AssetId
join Account acc on asset.pws_AccountId=acc.AccountId
where acc.AccountNumber in ('13636','172146','201194','34328','15236')
      and billing.pws_EndChargeDate< getutcDate() and assetser.statuscode=1
```

Comment: Have you tried converting `getutcdate()` to date like `CONVERT (date, GETUTCDATE())`? Could you also show the values for your **pws_EndChargeDate**?

Comment: When should a row not show up? If any entry in `pws_billingchargeitems` for the same `AccountNumber` has a `pws_EndChargeDate` in the future?

Comment: Try to do also process of elimination. Do the `SELECT` without the `WHERE` first. If the rows you are looking for are there then do the `SELECT` with `WHERE` but this time only the **acc.AccountNumber** in clause and so on and so forth. The problem could be your `JOIN` (if there are no proper matches) or the `WHERE` part etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That query simply won't do what you want it to do, as there's nothing in there to cope with the "don't include data if ANY of the dates are greater than today's date" rule.

You could do something like this (there's many ways to do this):

```
with badAssets AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        pws_AssetId
    FROM
        pws_billingchargeitems billing
        join pws_assetservice assetser on billing.pws_AssetId = assetser.pws_AssetId
        join pws_asset asset on asset.pws_assetId = billing.pws_AssetId
        join Account acc on asset.pws_AccountId = acc.AccountId
    WHERE
        acc.AccountNumber in ('13636','172146','201194','34328','15236')
        and assetser.statuscode = 1
        and billing.pws_EndChargeDate > getutcDate())
select distinct 
    billing.pws_AssetIdName
from 
    pws_billingchargeitems billing
    join pws_assetservice assetser on billing.pws_AssetId = assetser.pws_AssetId
    join pws_asset asset on asset.pws_assetId = billing.pws_AssetId
    join Account acc on asset.pws_AccountId = acc.AccountId
where 
    acc.AccountNumber in ('13636','172146','201194','34328','15236')
    and assetser.statuscode = 1
    and NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM badAssets WHERE badAssets.AssetId = billing.AssetId);
```

So we make a list of any assets where there's a end charge date in the future, then we reference this list at the end of your original query, instead of the old test, which only looked at one row of data at a time (and didn't work).